# ISAPI and Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, isapi

I am a Visual C++ programmer, mostly worked with USB/Serial communications and some HTTPS through OpenSSL. I am required to update an old VS 2003 project to VS 2010, but I have learned after some Googling that ISAPI was removed from MFC class wizard and they now supply an SDK . Does anyone know where to learn this ? I actually made searches on the internet but I was not luck to find a proper one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need MFC to build an ISAPI extension. Here is a very nice tutorial how to do it just with WinAPI: [What is an ISAPI Extension?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1432/What-is-an-ISAPI-Extension)

Comment: Thanks man! Just to be sure, this should work on newer versions of windows ? I really prefer WIN32 to MFC always except for GUis.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work on newer Windows, although I'll admit I never tried it with anything newer than IIS 6.0

Comment: Thanks, going to start the project tomorrow!

Comment: Hey thanks again man, the tutorial you showed us really put me in the right direction! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to building MFC ISAPI projects in VS2008, but it should work in VS2010 also - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2007/12/10/chttpserver-not-included-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx